# Group and count the nested json response - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

Im trying to bind value in Angular Material table, before that i need to process the GET response v

trying to achieve like below(just for understanding)

[image]

**my faulty code**

```
let filterByLocation = data.reduce((r, { group: location.country, ...object }) => {
    var finalArry = r.find(o => o.location === location);
    if (!finalArry) r.push(temp = { location, locationObj: [] });
    finalArry.locationObj.push(object);
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(filterByLocation);
```

thanks to @Nishant Dixit for his working snippet

```
const finalResponse = data.response.reduce((r, {
  location: {
    country: group
  },
  ...object
}) => {
  r[group] = r[group] || {
    location: group,
    locationObj: []
  };
  r[group].locationObj.push(object);
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(finalResponse)



const data = {
  "totalRec": 5,
  "response": [
  {
      "employee": {
        "uid": 1,
        "empName": "Jade"
      },
      "location": {
        "country": "UK",
        "subLocation": "London"
      },
      "department": {
        "sector": "IT"
      }
    },
    {
      "employee": {
        "uid": 2,
        "empName": "Mike"
      },
      "location": {
        "country": "UK",
        "subLocation": "Manchester"
      },
      "department": {
        "sector": "IT"
      }
    },
    {
      "employee": {
        "uid": 3,
        "empName": "Liya"
      },
      "location": {
        "country": "UK",
        "subLocation": "Southampton"
      },
      "department": {
        "sector": "HR"
      }
    },
    {
      "employee": {
        "uid": 3,
        "empName": "Brad"
      },
      "location": {
        "country": "USA",
        "subLocation": "Texas"
      },
      "department": {
        "sector": "IT"
      }
    },
    {
      "employee": {
        "uid": 3,
        "empName": "Brad"
      },
      "location": {
        "country": "USA",
        "subLocation": "Texas"
      },
      "department": {
        "sector": "NON-IT"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

but the problem is i'm getting result like

```
UK : {
location : "UK"
....
}
```

in html, i don't want to explicitly mention **UK** with dot operation like below, instead **row.location**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="facility">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Facility</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.UK.location}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

could someone tell me how to convert this output like

```
location: {
country : 'UK'
}
```

or any random name like

```
obj: {
location: 'UK'
//rest of values for grouping
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SathyaHere/sjcomuex/1/)

Thanks to every one

Comment: Could you please update your post with response json? It would be easier for us to understand.

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad updated..!!

Comment: That's how reduce is expected to return the response. I would rather create a new object iterating through the key and value.

Comment: Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects .Its trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const countryMap = {};
data.response.forEach(item => {
   countryMap[item.location.country] = [ ...( countryMap[item.location.country] || [] ), item];
});
```

Now, this is how the `countryMap` will look like:
[image]

Now, further to map it to the format you want, you can do this:

```
const mappedData = Object.entries(countryMap).map(entry => ({
   location: entry[0],
   response: entry[1]
}));
```

This will produce `mappedData` in this format:

[image]